# What is best to use as SetRepeating() does not work after 19 API

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I am doing some support work on an app that a previous placement student developed which is an app that takes in user input say 5. This then means that an alarm will sound every 5 minutes.

Her app has came back to me as the alarm has a mind of its own and has been inconsistent. Here is the code that she is using:

```
 alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        //set alert
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setTitle("IP Check frequency: " + time.getText() + " minutes")
                .setMessage("Processing commenced at \n" + startTime.getText())
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        if (currentTime.after(alarmTime)) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Missed first alert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);

                        i = Integer.parseInt(time.getText().toString());
                        scTime2 = (i * 60 * 1000); //5 minutes before set time

                        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeCommenced, scTime2, pendingIntent);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alert Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        stopped.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        commenced1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        //Change editText to TextView
                        time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        timeText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        timeText.setText(time.getText().toString());
                        processingText.setText(R.string.processing_commenced);

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

I can see that she is using `SetRepeating()` and I have read that from api level 19 plus this may be the problem.

I have tried using `SetExact()` but I am getting a red line under the variables inside the method.

Would anyone be able to tell me how I can keep the variables but get the consistency?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`setRepeating` and `setExact` take a different number of variables so you cant just use the same thing without making code changes.

If you want something to trigger at that exact time then you need to use `setExact` and every time the alarm fires you need to calculate the next time it should file automatically and use `setExact` again with a new time for it to trigger.

If you use `setRepeating` the OS can/will deffer the trigger time to a time where it can trigger multiple alarms together to save battery.

Comment: So how would I use setExact again then after the first time it fires? thanks for the reply @tyczj

Comment: yes after each time it fires you have to set a new alarm with setExact

Comment: Where would I place that then to ensure it repeats? what if its to repeat indefinitely then until it is stopped

Answer (score 0):

You are right. according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your
>   application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time
>   exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy
>   applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will
>   continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms,
>   treated as exact.

what they recommend you to do is to use [set()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) instead of [setRepeating()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) which would trigger once.
once the alarm is triggered, call the set() again inside the handler or pendingIntent.

Comment: Ive tried using set() there but I still get red lines. from the variables inside my method which can I take out?

Comment: Would you be able to give me some code on how to call the set() again inside a handler or my pending intent?